Fixed sidebar and fixed header with scrollable grid main content
I am having trouble fixing my layout.
Basically, I want to design a layout for my website project that has a sidebar and a header. I want the header and sidebar to be fixed, but the content of my main with a grid content is the only scrollable area.
However, when I put the place-content: center on my cards-container, it overlaps the header and the cards cannot be scrolled.


:root {
    --color-primary: #202225;
    --color-secondary: #5865f2;
    --color-scheme: light;
    --body-bg: #0e1217;
    --header-nav-bg: #0e1217;
    --card-bg: #1c1f26;
    --border-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.508);
}


body {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    font-family: "Fira Code", monospace;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 4.5rem 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr;

    grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "sidebar main";
}


/* Styling */
.header-nav {
    background-color: var(--header-nav-bg);
    border-block-end: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    grid-area: header;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(123, 123, 123, 0.495);
    grid-area: sidebar;
    padding-block: 1rem;
}

.main {
    grid-area: main;
}

.cards-container {
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(290px, 300px));
    padding-inline: 1.5rem;
    padding-block: 3rem;
}

.card {
    background-color: var(--card-bg);
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-inline: 1rem;
    padding-block: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: c1;
}
.card:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: c2;
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: c3;
}
.card:nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: c4;
}
.card:nth-child(5) {
    grid-area: c5;
}
.card:nth-child(6) {
    grid-area: c6;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Main with sidebar | Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header-nav"></header>
    <section class="sidebar">
          
    </section>
    <main class="main">
      <div class="cards-container">
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>



How do I fix this?

I would take a different approach to achieve this. I wouldn't use display: grid and I would use position: absolute to fix the position of heading and sidebar.
Have a look at the below snippet. You can adjust the height and width of header and sidebar as needed.


        :root {
            --color-primary: #202225;
            --color-secondary: #5865f2;
            --color-scheme: light;
            --body-bg: #0e1217;
            --header-nav-bg: #0e1217;
            --card-bg: #1c1f26;
            --border-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.508);
        }

        html{
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0;
        }


        /* Styling */
        .header-nav {
            background-color: var(--header-nav-bg);
            border-block-end: 1px solid var(--border-color);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            height: 60px;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: var(--body-bg);
            color: var(--color-secondary);
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-right: 1px solid rgba(123, 123, 123, 0.495);
            position: absolute;
            top: 61px;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 60px;
        }

        .main {
            margin: 61px 0 0 60px;
            height: calc(100% - 60px);
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .cards-container {
            background-color: var(--body-bg);
            display: grid;
            gap: 1rem;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(290px, 300px));
            padding-inline: 1.5rem;
            padding-block: 3rem;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .card {
            background-color: var(--card-bg);
            border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding-inline: 1rem;
            padding-block: 1rem;
            color: #fff;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Main with sidebar | Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
            href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
    />
</head>
<body>
<header class="header-nav"></header>
<section class="sidebar">

</section>
<main class="main">
    <div class="cards-container">
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
        <article class="card">card content</article>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>




but the bg of the card content is cut??

probably this is caused by the rendering in the small area... i can see it working fine in full screen

I see it now, but can you make this mobile friendly

Well the purpose is to give you an idea, help out and unblock you. I'm sure this is something that you can figure out given the above example!
